# How can I check if a parameter is AND is not a typeof string?

Tags: javascript, string, typeof

I am looking to solve an algorithm and I am running into some issues. Here I manage to check if it is a string by using `typeof` but I need to also check if it is not a string, I need help going about that.

```js
function isString(a, b, c) {
  if (typeof a, typeof b, typeof c === 'string') {
    return 'all parameters are strings';
  } else {
    return 'one of the parameters is not a strings';
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `if(typeof someVariable != "string") { ... }`.

Comment: as you already know, `typeof a === 'string' && typeof b === 'string' && typeof c === 'string'`

Comment: `typeof a, typeof b, typeof c === 'string'` is not valid JS

Comment: One more thing: if you are attempting to verify whether **all** of a, b and c are strings, then this is not the way to do it. You should use `if(typeof a === "string" && typeof b === "string" && typeof c === "string") { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

Your JS is invalid.

If you want to have only one test, you could do [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) after spreading the arguments to an array

```js
const isString = function(a, b, c) {
  return [...arguments].every(arg => typeof arg === "string") ? 'all parameters are strings' : 'one of the parameters is not a string'
};

console.log(isString("", "", ""))
console.log(isString("", 9, ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in this way

```js
function isString(a, b, c) {
  if ((typeof a && typeof b && typeof c) === 'string') {
    return 'all parameters are strings';
  } else {
    return 'one of the parameters is not a strings';
  }
}
```